# How to find out conditional probability distribution of dependent variable given the independent variable in quantile regression?

Tags: regression, distributions, conditional-probability, heteroscedasticity, quantiles

Suppose I'm given a problem of estimating future values of a particular entity, treating it as a linear regression problem, assumptions of linear regression model like heteroscedasticity are violated.
How do I find out the probability of dependent variable being less than a certain value with some confidence level?
Considering this problem as quantile regression problem, how do I find out which quantile regression line to fit for finding out the probability of dependent variable being less than a certain value given an independent variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to estimate $P(Y < 5 | X =16)$.  First you will input data $(X,Y)$; the following code simulates $n = 10000$ data values from $Y | X = x  \sim  N(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x, (0.25x)^2)$, where $\beta_0 = 2.0$ and $\beta_1 = 0.5$.  The $X$ data are generated from the uniform $U(10,20)$ distribution. In practice, you will just input these data from whatever source.

```
n = 10000
beta0 = 2.0; beta1 = 0.5
set.seed(12345)
X = runif(n, 10, 20)
Y = beta0 + beta1*X + .25*X*rnorm(n)
```

The true value of $P(Y < 5 | X =16)$ is 0.1056498, which is not known in practice, but is known here because the simulation model is known.

```
x0 = 16
y0 = 5
# True value of P(Y <y0 | X = x0), unknown in practice
pnorm(y0, beta0+beta1*x0, .25*x0)
```

Results:

```
> # True value of P(Y <y0 | X = x0), unknown in practice
> pnorm(y0, beta0+beta1*x0, .25*x0) 
[1] 0.1056498
```

Now, find the probability value such that the estimated $Y$ quantile at $X=16$ is equal to 5. You can do this by optimization:

```
library(quantreg)
fn  <- function(lgt) { 
prob = exp(lgt)/(1 + exp(lgt))
qtle = coefficients(rq(Y~X, tau=prob)) %*% c(1,x0)
return( (qtle-y0)^2 )
}

res = optimize(fn, lower = -10, upper=10)  
lgt = res$minimum
prob = exp(lgt)/(1+exp(lgt))

# Estimated P(Y <y0 | X = x0)
prob
```

The result is close to the true value:

```
> # Estimated P(Y <y0 | X = x0)
> prob
[1] 0.107628
>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer. One another quick question is there any literature review regarding the distribution of dependent variable, given the independent variable in quantile regression?

Comment: Is this a question about assumptions? I don't have any "review" paper at the top of my head; maybe others can chime in? Certainly no specific distribution is assumed, nor is homoscedasticity. A main assumption is that the quantiles of the conditional y|x distributions have the function form (eg linear, quadratic, exponential, logarithmic,...) that you you specify in your model, but other than that, the distributions can be anything. The usual independence assumptions are needed for validity of the reported standard errors, but can be relaxed if consistency is all that is required.